# Why am I unable to replicate this Matrix visual in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I cannot seem to be able to replicate the table where the measures are in the rows and years in columns. What am I missing?

[image: This is what I want my matrix to look like]

[image: Unfortunately, this is the best I can get my matrix to look like]

[image: And finally, if I reorder the Row and Columns this is what my matrix looks like]